# embedded image in textbox and email vb

Tags: vb.net, email

i try to display image in textbox then whatever is in textbox i am trying to send it in email.. all content is displayed and send in email but image is not displayed in textbox and also not send

```
txtEmailBody.Text = txtEmailBody.Text & "Tel:2345" & vbCrLf
    txtEmailBody.Text = txtEmailBody.Text & "Cell:435360 " & vbCrLf
    txtEmailBody.Text = txtEmailBody.Text & "Fax:3432456" & vbCrLf
    txtEmailBody.Text = txtEmailBody.Text & "Cell:+3456" & vbCrLf
    txtEmailBody.Text = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src=""../images/logo_deg.gif""></body></html>"
    Dim avHtml As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(txtEmailBody, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
    Dim pic1 As New LinkedResource("../images/logo_deg.gif", MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif)
    pic1.ContentId = "Pic1"
    avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(pic1)
```

but this shows error

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\images\logo_deg.gif'.
in this line

```
Dim pic1 As New LinkedResource("../images/logo_deg.gif", MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif)
```

when i add file in c drive this shows an error

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEmailBody="...

Comment: is the the image file on the given location?  (C:\Program Files\images\logo_deg.gi) also consider using Path.GetFullPath("../images/logo_deg.gif") and checks if the file acutally exists

Comment: no . this image in d driver there is folder in d drive and in that there is images folder and in that there is image

Comment: and when i add file in c drive this shows an error .. A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEmailBody="...

Comment: Well if your sending an email with an image you should either have uploaded it to web and you could use the **<img>** tag or just add it as attachement

Comment: i dont want to send image with attachement .. first i try to display in textbox then whatever is in textbox i am trying to send it in email.. all content is displayed and send in email but image is not displayed in textbox and also not send ..

Answer (score 0):

Ok first things first:

Read the [MSDN Textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see TextBox do not support images. So either you can:

- Create a Custom Textbox control
- Show directly the HTML Render with the image in WebBrowser
- Add a PictureBox next to the TextBox

Secondly you can easily add **Embeded Images** to Email with the simple use of **Base64** converstion

Add this as HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/*base64-data-string-here*/" />
```

And you can easily implement a function in your application to transform your images to **Base64**

```
Public Function ImageToBase64(image As Image, format As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As String
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        ' Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format)
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()

        ' Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
        Return base64String
    End Using
End Function
```

And then can just call it like this for example if have a local jpg file or can directly call it from **My.Resources** if take off the **Image.FromFile**

```
MyBody = <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/*" & ImageToBase64(Image.FromFile("Path to Image"), Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) &*/" />
```

Comment: where i add this in code or in html file ?<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/*base64-data-string-here*/" />  and what i add in base64-data ?

Comment: @user123 try to understand instead of copy pasting your code on internet i explained everything.